# MATLAB - FM Modulation

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to Frequency modulate a sine signal using Matlab. I have written the following code for the same:

```
fc = 5000; %Carrier Frequency
fs = 1000; %Signal Frequency
t = 0:0.00001:0.002;
x = sin(2*pi*fs*t);
dev = 50;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,x);
y = fmmod(x,fc,fs,dev);
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,y);
```

It is able to display the first plot command but not the second one. It throws an error: `` `fmmod' undefined near line 10 column 5 ``. What is wrong in the above code?

Comment: Where / how did you define `fmmod`?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't have the Communications System Toolbox.

Comment: As Doresoom pointed out, you probably don't have the Communications System Toolbox, which `fmmod` is part of. You can check which toolboxes you have by typing `ver` at the MATLAB command line.

Comment: Also, take into account that `fs` in `fmmod` is _sample rate_, not signal frequency. You should use a sample rate greater than `2*fc` (Nyquist criterion)

Comment: @Doresoom, I do have the Communication Systems Toolbox.

Comment: type `which fmmod` at the command line - what do you get?

Answer (score 2):

The following function will generate a FM modulated signal - it's not as good (flexible, etc) as `fmmod` but if you don't have the Comm System Toolbox this may be a good alternative.

```
function [s t] = makeFM( x, Fc, Fs, strength )
% for a signal x that modulates a carrier at frequency Fc
% produce the FM modulated signal
% works for 1 D input only
% no error checking

x = x(:);

% sampling points in time:
t = ( 0 : numel( x ) - 1 )' / Fs;

% integrate input signal
integratedX = cumsum( x ) / Fs;
s = cos( 2 * pi * ( Fc * t  + strength * integratedX ));
```

Put this in your path and call it with similar arguments to the `fmmod` function (but without optional parameters):

```
fc = 5000; %Carrier Frequency
fs = 1000; %Signal Frequency
t = 0:0.00001:0.002;
x = sin( 2*pi*fs*t );
dev = 50;
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(t,x);
y = makeFM(x, fc, 2.5*fc, dev); % note sampling frequency must be > carrier frequency!
subplot(2,1,2);
plot(t,y);
```

Let me know how that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is more simple approach

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
fm=input('Message Frequency=');
fc=input('Carrier Frequency=');
mi=input('Modulation Index=');
t=0:0.0001:0.1;
m=sin(2*pi*fm*t);
subplot(3,1,1);
plot(t,m);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Message Signal');
grid on;

c=sin(2*pi*fc*t);
subplot(3,1,2);
plot(t,c);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Carrier Signal');
grid on;

y=sin(2*pi*fc*t+(mi.*sin(2*pi*fm*t)));%Frequency changing w.r.t Message
subplot(3,1,3);
plot(t,y);
xlabel('Time');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('FM Signal');
grid on;
```