# how to integrate a saw tooth signal in matlab

Tags: matlab

i want to solve a problem 2.24 in Haykin communications systems using `matlab,` it wants to modulate a sawtooth signal using `fm` modulation and pm modulation, the pm is easy but the problem is in `fm` when i need to integrate the sawtooth to modulate it so any help and i dont want to use `fmmod` function in `matlab` i want it with equations. thank you

here is my used code

```
fs=100000;
fm=2;
fc=1000;
t=0:1/fs:6/fm;
m=sawtooth(2*pi*fm*t); 
plot(t,m);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should show your effort first in order to get more help. The code you have is just variable initialization nothing else.  What are the equations you are pointing at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First option:**

A simple implementation of the `fmmod` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097771/matlab-fm-modulation).

**Second option:**

Using MATLAB you can get the results easily. However, I do not know what you mean by "I want the equations".

- `fs` is the sampling rate of the signal (`fs` must be at least `2*fc`)
- `fc` is the carrier frequency
- `t` is the sampling time of the signal
- `x` is the signal (`sawtooth` here)
- `dev` is the frequency deviation in modulated signal
- `y` is the modulated signal
- `z` is the demodulated signal

You can use the following code:

```
fs=3000;
fm=20;
fc=1000;
t=[0:fs-1]/fs;
x=sawtooth(2*pi*fm*t); 
subplot(3,1,1);plot(x);
xlabel('main signal');
dev = 20;
y = fmmod(x,fc,fs,dev);
subplot(3,1,2);plot(y);
xlabel('modulated signal');
z = fmdemod(y,fc,fs,dev);
subplot(3,1,3);plot(z);
xlabel('demodulated signal');
```

The result is shown in the following image:

[image]

Comment: thank you very much you answer is very helpful, i mean by equations that i want to implement the fm modulation equation that is s=cos(2*pi*fc+kf*int(m));

Comment: so the problem was to integrate the signal and the signal is discreet so i found this helpful function that integrates discreet vectors here is (cumtrapz) so i  implemented this code and was correct and like your code

Answer (score 0):

```
fs=10000;
fm=1;
fc=10;
t=0:1/fs:6/fm;
kf=25;
kp=30;
m=1+sawtooth(2*pi*fm*t);
m_int=cumtrapz(t,m);
s_fm=2*cos((2*pi*fc*t)+kf*m_int);
s_pm=2*cos((2*pi*fc*t)+kp*m);
subplot(3,1,1);plot(t,m);
title('wave form of sawtooth modulating signal');
xlabel('time (sec)');
ylabel('amplitude');

subplot(3,1,2);plot(t,s_fm);
title('wave form of FM modulated signal');
xlabel('time (sec)');
ylabel('amplitude');

subplot(3,1,3);plot(t,s_pm);
title('wave form of PM modulated signal');
xlabel('time (sec)');
ylabel('amplitude');
```